# How can I download videos from a website like MITWorld?

Tags: video, download, streaming

How can I download [MITWorld](http://mitworld.mit.edu/video/308) videos?

Are there any programs for this?

Answer (score 2):

I tried [Replay media catcher](http://www.applian.com/download-videos) on this and it worked..it can download the rtmp stream that is hidden behind

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the videos are [available on itunes](http://deimos3.apple.com/WebObjects/Core.woa/Browse/mit.edu).  I don't have itunes myself so I can't actually check if they're all there or under what terms, but it might be worth checking.

Answer (score 0):

If you have firefox you could:

1: Go to the page
2: Click on tools --> Page Info --> Media
3: Look for a file that is embedded and then click save as.

Sometimes this works sometimes it doesn't

Hope it helps

Answer (score -2):

you can use orbit downloader' s grab++ application. orbit downloader can be downloaded from http://www.orbitdownloader.com/

you can find out how to use grab++ in faq section

Comment: Didn't work as expected

Comment: doesn't work on MIT world videos